# http response Header information

Tags: java, json, http

so it may be a stupid question for some if not for all, but i have this response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Atr: 10
X-Atr2: 1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2016 09:17:26 GMT
```

and the result that goes with it :

```
{"site": [
  {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "James"
  },
   {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Katia"
  },
  {
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Sam"
  }
```

What i want to do is to change **HTTP/1.1 200 OK** in case i get this i get something like **HTTP/1.1 206 you have some results**  and in the same time have the display the JSON result. and in case that we don't have any results it would be like:  **HTTP/1.1 400 didn't find any result** AND the JSON result would be like :

```
[]
```

So what i have tried is the following :

```
if (response.getSite().size() <= 0) {
     responseHttp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED, "you have some    results"); 
    } else {

 responseHttp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED, "you have some    results");}
```

The thing is in both cases it edited HTTP/1.1 but doesn't display any message nor the JSON results.

hope i well explained my problème thank you for your time and help.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 didn't find any result - SHOULD be HTTP 404 instead

Comment: ok ok i agree but how can i change it my code, knowing that with sendError it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the status code and the message accordingly. You did set SC_ACCEPTED for both cases.

Btw. `SC_ACCEPTED` is 202.
For "didn't find any result" you can take `SC_NOT_FOUND` (404);
Alternatively you can just use ints

You can find the `SC_...` values [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html).

If you want to send the message AND the json, you might need to embed the json string into the message. Otherwise you might need to just send the json in the body and move the message to the HTTP Status Description in the header. The method `sendError(int sc, String msg)` creates a HTML like page with your message embedded (see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int,%20java.lang.String))).

Comment: Thank you for your answer,i have tried with `responseHttp.setStatus(sc);`with an int sc=202; and it worked but with `responseHttp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED, "Some sites returned");` or `      responseHttp.setStatus(responseHttp.SC_FOUND,sm);` it doesnt work ! Can you explain more your last paragraph please ?

Comment: What exactly is not clear? How did you return the message and/or json in the working scenario (after setStatus(sc))? Btw. `setStatus(sc, sm)` is deprecated and replaced by the method you used.

Comment: yes i saw that `setStatus(sc, sm)` is decrected, the method `sendError(int sc, String msg)` is returning me `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant you want to set the response status so I suggest to use something like:

```
if (response.getSite().size() <= 0) {
     responseHttp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Bad Request"); 
    } else {
     responseHttp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
     //your other codes for sending JSON response goes here:
  }
```

Comment: the second one works, so if i have some results i can see the header changes! but in case no result is found  i get this : `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` Any idea ?

Comment: @MehaibiaOumaima try responseHttp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST); and see if it helps instead of sendError

Comment: nothing i have the following result `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Total-Count: 0
X-Result-Count: 1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2016 12:35:51 GMT

{"site":[]}`

Comment: @MehaibiaOumaima are you sure you reach the code in the "if" part? put a debugging breakpoint or a simple println to check you reach there

Comment: `X-Total-Count: 0 X-Result-Count: 1` leads me to the thought, that there might be something wrong with the condition check. Maybe you can try to debug (server-side, e.g. by logging), where in your if-clause you end up.

Comment: @Pooya it doesnt enter my if clause :( even if i have 0 result,i don't get it! i'll keep looking; once i will find it i'll post you the whole answer thank you for your answers and time